# PostSharp: removing/replacing backing fields

Tags: c#, postsharp

I am trying to find if PostSharp could be easily used to change the structure of the class by removing/replacing backing fields.

Here is the sample:

Let's say, I have a following entity

```
class DataItem
{
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public Decimal? HourlyRateMon { get; set; }
  public Decimal? HourlyRateTue { get; set; }
  public Decimal? HourlyRateWed { get; set; }
  public Decimal? HourlyRateThu { get; set; }
  public Decimal? HourlyRateFri { get; set; }
}
```

which will use 4 + 8 + 5*20 + 16 bytes overhead on 64-bit = 128 bytes per instance.

What I would like to do is to apply an aspect that will minimize the object's memory footprint by packing the nullable decimals - something like

```
internal class DataItem
{
  private CompactDecimal _hourlyRateFri;
  private CompactDecimal _hourlyRateMon;
  private CompactDecimal _hourlyRateThu;
  private CompactDecimal _hourlyRateTue;
  private CompactDecimal _hourlyRateWed;

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public decimal? HourlyRateMon
  {
    get { return _hourlyRateMon; }
    set { _hourlyRateMon = value; }
  }

  public decimal? HourlyRateTue
  {
    get { return _hourlyRateTue; }
    set { _hourlyRateTue = value; }
  }

  public decimal? HourlyRateWed
  {
    get { return _hourlyRateWed; }
    set { _hourlyRateWed = value; }
  }

  public decimal? HourlyRateThu
  {
    get { return _hourlyRateThu; }
    set { _hourlyRateThu = value; }
  }

  public decimal? HourlyRateFri

  {
    get { return _hourlyRateFri; }
    set { _hourlyRateFri = value; }
  }
}

internal struct CompactDecimal
{
  public uint Offset;

  public static implicit operator decimal?(CompactDecimal d)
  {
    // here I can, for instance, go to a shared stream at the stream offset and read the decimal
  }

  public static implicit operator CompactDecimal(decimal? d)
  {
    // here I can, for instance, serialize the decimal to a shared stream and get the stream offset
  }
}
```

which will use 4 + 8 + 5*4 + 16 bytes overhead on 64-bit = 48 bytes per instance, saving 80 bytes/instance. In case we need to store millions of instances, it gives us a substantial savings of memory.

I tried to create a LocationInterceptionAspect-derived attribute, but I did not get the expected result - not only the original backing fields still were there, but also I had 10 instances of TestAttribute (5 properties, get/set for each):

```
// Fields
[NonSerialized]
private TestAttribute <>z__aspect10;
[NonSerialized]
private TestAttribute <>z__aspect11;
[NonSerialized]
private TestAttribute <>z__aspect12;
[NonSerialized]
private TestAttribute <>z__aspect13;
[NonSerialized]
private TestAttribute <>z__aspect4;
[NonSerialized]
private TestAttribute <>z__aspect5;
[NonSerialized]
private TestAttribute <>z__aspect6;
[NonSerialized]
private TestAttribute <>z__aspect7;
[NonSerialized]
private TestAttribute <>z__aspect8;
[NonSerialized]
private TestAttribute <>z__aspect9;
private decimal? <HourlyRateFri>k__OriginalField;
private decimal? <HourlyRateMon>k__OriginalField;
private decimal? <HourlyRateThu>k__OriginalField;
private decimal? <HourlyRateTue>k__OriginalField;
private decimal? <HourlyRateWed>k__OriginalField;
```

Either I am doing something wrong or the PostSharp does not support what I want to achieve.

The TestAttribute does not do anything now -

```
[Serializable]
public class TestAttribute : LocationInterceptionAspect, IInstanceScopedAspect
{
  public override void CompileTimeInitialize(LocationInfo targetLocation, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
  {
    //base.CompileTimeInitialize(targetLocation, aspectInfo);
  }

  #region <<< Public methods >>>
  public Object CreateInstance(AdviceArgs adviceArgs)
  {
    return MemberwiseClone();
  }

  public override void OnGetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
  {
    //args.
    //base.OnGetValue(args);
  }

  public override void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
  {
    //base.OnSetValue(args);
  }

  public void RuntimeInitializeInstance()
  {
  }
  #endregion
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you also need to count the memory used by the stream itself. Basically you would just replace bool in the Nullable with uint index and thus save nothing. Additionally, note that on 64bit machines, memory is padded to 8 bytes and thus `decimal?` is 24 bytes large.

The way to save the memory would be to pack bools from nullable types into a bitmap. However, you would need to introduce a field and change types of backing field. PostSharp Aspect Framework does not support this.

Other way to go would be not to make properties automatic and override getter and setter using an aspect that would get or set the value using an introduced interface. However in that case you would need to have 2 more objects per instance - instance-level aspect object with a bitmap and decimal array to hold values. That would make such an overhead that memory would saved only after you use 8 nullable values in a class.

A slight improvement would be to have a common base class that would have the array and the bitmap. You would not need instance-level aspect anymore, you will have just the decimal array and bitmap saved in the base class fields. This method will save a memory from 5 nullable values up.